# How to execute all SQL files in a folder using a BATCH file and also log the result of each file in the <SQL filename>.log?

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

I want to execute all SQL files in a folder and its sub folder using a BATCH file and also log the result of each file in the .log.

For example, I have 2 folders Config and Data, and each has 20 SQL files (appuser.sql, tenant.sql and so on) along with a LOG empty sub-folder in each folder.

Now, I want the BATCH to execute all the SQL files and the output of each file should be logged in a separate file (appuser.log, tenant.log and so on) in the LOG sub-folder in each of the folders.

Also, suggest me the best site to learn SQL related BATCH scripting.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Another option would be to create a program to recursively concatenate all of your sql scripts into one file and upload that. Why do you need each file to have an associated log file? Wouldn't one log file suffice for the entire batch?

Comment: You should be able to do that using SQLCMD if you are using MS Sql Server

Comment: If you need code written for you urgently, maybe you should hire a programmer.

Comment: [There you go](http://google.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for /r "your_path" %%i in (*.sql) do (
  sqlcmd -i "%%i" -o "log\%%i.log"
)
```

Comment: Imo it should be `sqlcmd -i "%%~fi" -o "%%~dpilog\%%~nxi.log"`

Comment: Thanks @elzooilogico